# Checking and unchecking checkbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have Textbox with autocomplete property and checkboxlist in asp.net C#.when i check the checkbox,it have to place it's content in checkbox.when i type the content in textbox,it has to check the appropriate checkbox in checkboxlist.I've to do it in Jquery.
Eg:[image: My picture]
In this picture after i typed those values,appropriate check boxes have to be checked.Help me guys.Thanks in Advance

Comment: create a fiddle for this

Comment: I dont think this is the proper way but it will solve the problem .. bind change event on the textbox and split the textbox value using ";" on change then check if the last element value present for any checkbox  if exists check that checkbox

Comment: and which plugin are you using for making the checkbox list

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.10.2 optimus

Comment: Can you please provide HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a global variable, or parent scope variable, and update it when check, uncheck, input value in `textbox`.

check my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5txoqhpL/4/